# PHP - Creating an XML file from an Object

Tags: php, xml

I have a simple method inside a class that returns an Address based on a id.

For example:

```
$address = Address::get_by_id($id);
```

I'm calling the method based on a GET value. The function loads some data from the database and creates an XML file and then makes a map.

```
$map = new Map();
$map->create_address_xml($address);
```

Everything works as I expect when the URL is : /page?id=123

The problem I have is when I introduce a rewritten url.

For example

```
^pretty-url/([0-9]+)$ /page?id=$1 [L]
```

When the url is rewritten and I pass the $address object to $map->create_address_xml, it doesn't work.

I get no errors, so I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

PS. My first question on here (after much searching!) Please let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: Have you checked `$id` value? have you checked `$address`? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Sure have. The weird thing is the $address object builds a page with headings, text, image and that works on both ugly and pretty urls. The only thing that doesn't work is the function to create the XML file.

Comment: I've even done things like:

$name = $address->name

$map->create_address_xml($name);

And that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Address fields in a json and Then convert it in XML.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect.